# GCC7 Deduce in same class the presence of a const modifier

Tags: c++, this, constants, c++17, decltype

I originally wanted to deduce within a class whether it was declared with or without a const modifier. As many of you pointed out, it is the variable itself which is declared as const (and not the class). Thanks for making this clear. The error message make now totally sense to me. So, it is more a design problem.

What I want is a struct that behaves like a random access container and provides some functions like `iterator begin(){...}`, `const_iterator cbegin(){...}`, and especially the `value_type operator[](size_type idx){...}` and some more. I want to provide as much functions as possible, no matter if the instance is const or not. So, in practice `A a{}; a.begin();` will return a non-constant reference of the value type of `A` and  `a.cbegin()` an const reference. Whereas for `A const ac{};` `ac.begin()` and `ac.cbegin()` should have the same constant reference type. But probably these use cases do not make sense.
I could restrict to use cases where only the non-const `a` in combination with non-const iterators are callable (i.e. allow `a.begin()`, but not `a.cbegin()`), and `ac` only with const iterators (i.e. `ac.cbegin()`, but not `ac.begin()`). Does this makes sense?

The reason behind this weird attempt is that in my implementation there does not exist ONE underlying container, but two helper containers: a bit vector and a compressed sequence. Depending on the content of the bit vector I either return a special symbol or a letter of the compressed sequence (see extended code example).
Also, I do not use the std::iterator but an own implementation. Note `(*host)[idx + offset]` returns a temporary, that's probably why I get after the output a segmentation fault.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename container_t>
struct my_iterator
{
private:
    using reference = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<container_t>::value,
                    typename container_t::const_reference,
                    typename container_t::reference>;
    using size_type = typename container_t::size_type;
    size_type offset = 0;
    typename std::add_pointer_t<container_t> host{nullptr};
public:
    my_iterator(container_t & host_, size_type offset_) : host{&host_}, offset{offset_} {}
    reference operator[](typename container_t::size_type const idx)
    {
        return (*host)[idx + offset];
    }
};

template<typename sequence_t>
struct A  // implements some features of the container concept
{
    using const_reference = typename sequence_t::const_reference;
    using reference = typename sequence_t::value_type;
    using iterator = my_iterator<A>;
    using const_iterator = my_iterator<A const>;
    using value_type = typename sequence_t::value_type;
    using size_type = typename sequence_t::size_type;

    // data structures internally used to resolve random access
    std::vector<unsigned int> bit_vector{1,0,1,0,0,0};
    std::vector<char> text{'h', 'w'};
    constexpr char static const cash = '$';

public:
    // provide some container functions, like begin, end, cbegin, cend
    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator{*this, 0};
    }

    const_iterator cbegin() const
    {
        return const_iterator{*this, 0};
    }
    // ...

    size_type rank(size_type idx) const
    {
        return std::accumulate(bit_vector.begin(),  bit_vector.begin()+idx, 0);
}

constexpr reference operator[](size_type const idx) const
{
    assert(idx < bit_vector.size());
    if (bit_vector[idx])
        return cash;
    return text[idx - rank(idx)];
}
};

int main(){
    /* non const usage */
    A<std::vector<char>> a{};
    auto it_a = a.begin();
    std::cout << it_a[0] << std::endl;
    /*  const usage */
    A<std::vector<char>> const a_const{};
    /* does not compile, because of non matching types */
    auto it_const_a = a_const.begin();
    std::cout << "it_const_a[0] = " << it_const_a[1] << std::endl;
    /* does compile, but gives segmentation fault */
    auto it_const_a2 = a_const.cbegin();
    std::cout << "it_const_a2[0] = " << it_const_a2[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `this` only exists within member functions; that's the only situation where an object is aware of its own existence. Your reason for wanting this sounds a bit strange. If you explain the connection between this and overloading the `[]` operator, you might get help with solving your actual problem.

Comment: also, `A<std::vector<int>> a();` is the declaration of a function returning `A<std::vector<int>>`. You should write `A<std::vector<int>> a;` instead.

Comment: You can't do what you're suggesting because `const` applies to the variable, not the class.  But this definitely seems like an X-Y problem.  It's not clear exactly what you're after, but perhaps you can get what you need with just `ret_type1 operator[](size_t);` and `ret_type2 operator[](size_t) const;` overloads.

Comment: if you provide a `const` and a non-`const` overload for `operator[]` you know if `this` is `const` or not, thus I dont really understand the question. Anyhow, a non-const instance can easily be referenced as `const`, eg `A a; const A& b = a;`

Answer (score 2):

> I'd would like to deduce within a class whether it was declared with or without a const modifier.

*Classes* are not declared with `const` qualifier. Those qualifiers are for declaration of *variables*.

There is no `this` outside of non-static member functions, as the error message explains. Member types (aliases) of a class do not depend on the instance(s), and so cannot depend on the constness of an instance.

In any case, I suspect that you assume `std::iterator` to be an iterator. It is *not* an iterator. It is a base class that can be used to avoid repeating a few definitions when writing a (custom) iterator. And this kind of confusion is probably a reason why it is going to be deprecated in the upcoming standard version.